# Vector of pointers to Objects - Memory leaks

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pointers to class objects. These class objects invoke "new" as well to create an array.

I'm trying to avoid memory leaks, so I created a destructor which returns the object's array back to freestore.

```
laboratory::~laboratory()
{
   delete Users;   // Users is an array from the heap
}
```

When I try to delete each element of the pointer vector, however, the program crashes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
    delete labVector[i];
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Pasted code here: http://pastie.org/4168453

Class and function definitions are below main(). Sorry for pasting it this way, I was using a header file and 2 source files.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example showing the problem. It is hard to tell what is going on. What is `Users`, who and how allocates that? How and where `labVector` is defined, etc?

Comment: Also, for correctness sake, use 'delete[]' on a new'ed array. Other than that, context please :)

Comment: Yes, that was quite stupid of me. It was the delete [] Users after all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete Users;   // Users is an array from the heap
```

Well then that's wrong.  Should be

```
delete [] Users;
```

Anything you `new` with `[]` gets a `delete` with `[]`.

On a side note; do you *really* need a vector of pointers here? It's pretty darn rare to actually need that (though you see it a lot) and it completely negates the container's ability to manage memory for you, requiring you to loop through and deallocate every element.

vectors use dynamic memory behind the scenes for each element.  You could us a vector of smart pointers or even a `vector<vector<T>>` (though, if performance is of the utmost concern, a jagged array may be a better choice. Don't assume that though).

Comment: Wanna explain the downvote please, or are you just on a downvoting spree?

Comment: Should definitely not, ever, be `delete [] Users`.

Comment: @DeadMG: That's about the dumbest thing I have ever heard.  Give people practical advice, not religious advice.

Comment: Practical advice is that `delete` and `delete[]` lead to double delete, memory corruption, memory leaks, and UB by using the wrong deallocation, not to mention other stuff. `std::vector<T>` does not have those problems. Those tools exist *because* manually deallocating your own memory is error-prone at *best*.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes, that is reasonable, and far removed from your initial statement.  There are many good reasons to `new` up some memory, though they should be well understood.

Comment: No, there *might* be some *very niche* situation when you want to write your own class that manages some resource- although the Standard solutions are so generic, I've never, ever seen any situation which they could not be applied to. However, in that case, you would *still* wrap it in a class, and not allocate or deallocate it at the point of use.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you absolutely *need* to do this on your own, consider using a Boost [`ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few choices:

1. You can make it clear that the vector does not own the objects in it, only the pointers to them. It then becomes the responsibility of all code that uses this vector to allocate and delete the objects itself.
2. You can use a boost `ptr_vector` for this. The vector will own the objects it contains pointers to. You'll need to write a helper function to duplicate the objects so that `x = y;` will work. (Since `x` will need to own its own copy of every object in `y`.)
3. You can use smart pointers, such as `boost::shared_ptr`, for this. If you do `x = y;`, the two vectors will refer to the *same* objects, such that changing the value in one will change the value in the other. The vectors will share ownership of the objects and can return safe references to the objects in them. The objects will self-destruct when they are no longer needed.
4. You can use a vector of `boost::any` objects. This performs poorly but is very flexible.

But it really comes down to the classic question: *What are you trying to do?* Are you trying to manage the lifetimes of objects? If you duplicate a vector, what should happen? Should that duplicate the underlying objects? Do you need polymorphism? Are you using pointers to avoid slicing? And so on. Explain your use case and you'll get better solution suggestions.

**Update**: Your use of a vector of pointers seems simple and safe (so long as you don't try to copy-construct a vector, assign it, or anything like that). That your `delete` loop is crashing suggests possibly a bug in your destructor.

**Update2**: Yep.

```
laboratory::~laboratory()
{
    delete stationUsers;
}
```

This is wrong because `stationUsers` wasn't allocated with `new` but with `new[]`.

Comment: +1 great answer, though I think the OP should understand why `delete someArray` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know without more code but consider:

```
delete[] Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not allocate an array from the heap yourself. Use `std::vector<User>`. In addition, you should *never, ever* use `delete` or `delete[]` yourself. Always use a class-based solution such as smart pointers or `std::vector` to manage your memory.

Comment: -1 because saying things like *you should never, ever use delete or delete[]* is just silly and borders on religious.  I am leery of code that uses operator `new` myself, but to claim that there are absolutely no circumstances in which you should dynamically allocate your own memory is just plain ignorant.

Comment: @EdS.: Provide a counter-example.

Comment: Ok.  I work on a system that, among other things, performs a lot of image processing.  Using a `vector<vector<int32_t>>` to hold data is a no-go.  We run into needless allocations and you lose locality of data, and cache misses slow you down.  A lot. So, you use an array and guess what?  It's fast.  You handle it properly and deterministically *because you know what you are doing and you have a good reason for doing so*.  Now, I did end up writing my own RAII-type container for this, but I still used new and delete in there.

Comment: @EdS.: You could instead have simply written a cheap wrapper on `vector<int32_t>(n * m)`, which is what Boost::Multiarray did.

Comment: Second; ever programmed for a micro controller where the STL implementation was utter garbage?  Where resources are at a premium and unnecessary allocations kill you?  I do.  So, while the reasons to  dynamically allocate and delete memory yourself are few and far between these days, they do exist.

Comment: @EdS.: Ever considered that microcontrollers are barely 1% of the software market? They are way too niche to warrant consideration in a general-purpose question.

Comment: @DeadMG: I did, did you read the whole response?  I still have to use `new` and `delete` to implement the wrapper.  But of course, you say I should *never* do that, right?

Comment: @DeadMG: Perhaps you don't understand the definition of "never".  It does not mean "in less than 1% of cases" it means absolutely in no circumstances.  That was my problem, and to not tell the OP that they need to use `delete []` when deallocating a dynamically allocated array is just silly.  Tell them where they went wrong so that they understand their folly and *then* suggest a better alternative

Comment: Wait, wait... 1%?  Are you kidding?  Go and count the number of electronic devices you have in your home that run software.  Tell me how many are PC's.  embedded code is *everywhere*, regardless of whether or not it is a foreign concept to you.

Comment: @EdS.: The vast majority of them all run the same programs. The actual task of programming them is barely 1% of all programming. ... and even if your STL implementation sucks, then just roll your own- don't go down to C. Not to mention that most microcontrollers like that don't have a high quality STL implementation because they can't dynamically allocate.

Comment: @EdS.: You don't need to use `new` and `delete` to wrap a `vector`.

Comment: ...except I explained why using multiple vectors as a 2d array was a bad idea... regardless, I think my point is clear.  I actually *agree* with what I *think* you mean.  I disagree strongly with statements like *thou shalt never use `new` and `delete`*

Comment: I think it's better if they understand why it is a bad idea in general rather than simply being told.  I'd also like to see some data to back up your "tiny fraction" statement.  I work in a systems group on some pretty cool stuff and I don't think I am part of a tiny fraction of programmers out there.  Perhaps a tiny fraction of those on SO.

Comment: @EdS. There is a question on Programmers, which suggests that the expense of developing micro-controller programs is about $3.4bn a year, and all program development is about $300bn a year, as of 2011 or so. And I agree that they should know why it is a bad idea. It is, however, most definitely a *tiny fraction*. Why don't you come to the C++ chat? Mods gonna spank this comment thread soon enough.

Comment: And I didn't mean wrap *multiple* vectors. I meant wrap *one*. [For example](http://pastebin.com/t9iExNQJ). This is already a solved problem anyway, with Boost.MultiArray.

Comment: C++ chat?  Didn't know it existed (I've been around since beta, guess I should get out more...).  I'll check it out sometime.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the others comments, your code has an Off-by-One error. This code references one past the end of your array.

```
for(int i = 0; i `<` vectorSize; i++)
    delete labVector[i];
```